# Sharing assemblies without GAC

Tags: .net, shared-libraries, gac

We have several solutions, stand-alone applications that uses the same licensing and update service which is currently located in the GAC.

Once again we've encountered versioning issues.

Is there an elegant way to share an assembly at the client computer without using GAC?

Comment: The CLR very strongly discourages this.  To avoid versioning issues.  You can bake your own assembly search algorithm with AppDomain.AssemblyResolve, it isn't elegant.

Comment: Take a look at the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819689/alternatives-to-gac-for-sharing-code-between-mvc-sites