# Alternatives to GAC for sharing code between mvc sites

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, gac

Currently, we have c# object registered in the gac which we use to output a html/string which acts as a common menu for our web applications.

The benefit of the gac registered object is that we can update the gac object and all applications that reference it get the updates very efficiently.  The html menu references some js and css resources at a common location.

The c# object does perform some logic based on servers/environments etc.

Are there alternatives other than GAC objects to perform similar functionality.

I had considered reference a mvc view from another project/controller but there was latency issues (i.e. the menu was rendered after the rest of the page).  I feel it works best when rendered as part of the page.

other thoughts/ideas/options?

Comment: What about a NuGet package?

Comment: GAC is nothing but trouble! In my experience, it always adds unnecessary scope especially to testing with very little benefits. We have created internal nuget server using http://inedo.com/proget/overview internally. It works very well for us.

Comment: We have nuget setup as well, but this means that the object/dll has to be within the bin director of the project.  We have 50-100 projects.  Making updates to that many projects even with nuget is too difficult and time consuming.

Comment: I recognize GAC is going away however I have yet to read alternatives which accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @David, Do you really have 50-100 projects on one server, all of them relying on some arbitrary library in the GAC to function properly? It sounds horrible to maintain and it sounds like you're just waiting for one of the sub-systems to work differently without noticing and have bugs that are hard to find. I'd suggest setting up your CI environment to re-deploy all the sites if there's a change in a dependency that requires an update.

Comment: Problem exists between GAC and Chair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use web.config to manually instruct each site to find a particular assembly at a common location:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4191fzwb(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4191fzwb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

From the article:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="myAssembly"
                           publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
                           culture="en-us" />
         <codeBase version="2.0.0.0"
                   href="http://www.litwareinc.com/myAssembly.dll"/>
       </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Alternatively, you could setup "probing" to search  entire directories for your common libraries (also from the article):

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The above uses href path file:///e:/{rest of path} instead of href (seems this may be a little more secure and not quite as available via http which could be good)

      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="ComponentName" publicKeyToken="key123" culture="neutral" />
        <codeBase version="1.0.0.0" href="file:///E:/shared/1.0.0.0/ComponentName.dll" />
      </dependentAssembly>

Comment: Is it possible to specify multiple locations i.e. file:///e:/... and file:///c:/..

Answer (score 2):

In a decade I never used the GAC and although I setup an internal NuGet server via TeamCity and let CI do all the rebuilding when my shared libs are updated, I wouldn't use that here, I don't think.

My gut says to build a little web service for this kind of stuff and have the other servers send up their data/state in an extensible form (JSON/XML) i.e. the data needed for the logic based on servers/environment, and have the web service perform the logic and send back either data in a model to translate into HTML, or HTML itself.

Add some cache-control headers, then I'd update the web service logic when I want to change the behaviour.

**Edit**

I just remembered that Martin Fowler blogged about this approach.

http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html

So this is how I've worked for several years now. Of course we have programming logic in DLLs, but for business logic, rather than having it in libraries, we place it in many little web APIs and then it also open for other languages and mash-ups, PowerShell etc.

I guess what I'm saying is that a different architectural approach could help.

By-the-way, I first heard of this when I read, in 2008 I think, that Amazon's home page gathers data from >100 small web services.

Comment: For completeness, here's the Amazon architecture in 2007: "Between 100-150 services are accessed to build a page." - http://highscalability.com/amazon-architecture

Comment: Yes I considered this approach. In the above scenario(ours) we would have to get the html/string from c# through a service/http and then inject into the page.  While this works, seems like it may not be the most optimum performance wise.  i.e. while on the server hitting a service for content from c# (we can't do this client side due to lag/latency issues with page build).  

I am open to this idea but hitting web service from c# on server seems like extra layer when alternative is dll in shared location.

Comment: If the request is the same each time, or there's a finite set of variants, then with proper cache-control, the request won't make it out of the local Windows HTTP stack. You can also fire the request off before doing other server-side work, and I'd suggest if on MVC using Async actions `public async Task<ActionResult> YourActionAsync()` so you don't block worker threads.